WireGuard: three peers connected linearly, UDP over TCP for one connection only
I have three peers on a WireGuard network:

Peer J is behind a standard corporate firewall blocking all outgoing UDP,
Peer S is a server with static IP, and
Peer P is my smartphone.

   No UDP out;
  +-----------+  (Static IP)
  | Peer J ---|--- Peer S ------ Peer P
  +-----------+         [Regular wg]
So, UDP over TCP

I want to connect peer P to peer J (P ssh into J) via WireGuard, where J and S are connected by UDP over TCP (using wangyu-/udp2raw), while S and P have a vanilla standard WireGuard UDP connection.
Here's my attempt thus far:
Peer J
[Interface]
# PublicKey = E8K...
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.0.6/24
MTU = 1342
PreUp = /usr/bin/udp2raw -c -l 127.0.0.1:50001 -r <S's internet IP>:443 -k "secret" -a >/var/log/udp2raw.log 2>&1 &
PostDown = killall udp2raw || true

# Peer S
[Peer]
PublicKey = Yf3...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/32
PersistentKeepalive = 120
Endpoint = 127.0.0.1:50001

Peer S
[Interface]
# PublicKey = Yf3...
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.0.0/24
MTU = 1342
ListenPort = 80
PreUp = /usr/bin/udp2raw -s -r 127.0.0.1:80 -l <S's LAN IP>:443 -k "secret" -a >/var/log/udp2raw.log 2>&1 &
PreDown = killall udp2raw || true

# Peer J
[Peer]
PublicKey = E8K...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32
PersistentKeepalive = 120

# Peer P
[Peer]
PublicKey = wlx...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.19/32

Peer P
[Interface]
PublicKey = wlx...
Address = 10.0.0.19/32
MTU = 1342

# Peer S
[Peer]
PublicKey = Yf3...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = <S's internet IP>:80

Problem: Peer P cannot ping peer J. But peer J can ping peer S and vice versa; and peer S can ping peer P and vice versa. The traceroute of P to J is:
raceroute to 10.0.0.6 (10.0.0.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
  1  ip-10-0-0-0.region.compute.internal (10.0.0.0)  54.950 ms  54.063 ms  53.245 ms
  2  * * *
  3  * * *

So there is something wrong with the routing at S, but I can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

Is there a particular reason you are putting P and J on different subnets? Oh, wait, re-reading the setup ... why do P and S have two P addresses?

@JaromandaX Thanks for pointing that out. I've simplified them to just one subnet.

AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/32 Why 32?

Btw, you should also avoid using 10.0.0.0 as the IP of S, since in /24 that's the subnet ID. Besides, IP forwarding needs to be enabled (sysctl) and allowed (iptables and/or nftables) on S for the "clients" to talk to each other (or really, talk to anything other than the "server").

@TomYan Your solution worked! I think the key was the wrong subnet mask on AllowedIPs of peer S as written in peer J's config. I've also changed the IP of S on the way. Will you write an answer so that I can accept it?

The problem was that J has AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/32 in its [Peer] section for S, which means only traffics destined at 10.0.0.0 would be be sent to S.
In order for traffics destined at any host within the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet (such as 10.0.0.19) to be sent to S for further forwarding, AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24 should be used.
